# How to change Color define in Xaml Resources in code (UWP)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[UWP]

I have many grids with color binding from App.xaml

MainPage.xaml ...

```
        <Grid
            Height="45"
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            Background="{ThemeResource MyColor}">
```

App.xaml

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Dark">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor">#FFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
```

Then I want to change all of its, in code like this

```
    Application.Current.Resources["MyColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 101, 34));
```

But it not work. May I miss something? When I navigate to another page and navigate back, above code throw a System.Exception

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work?  Does it throw an exception, does the background color of the `Grid`s fail to change?

Comment: Color not change. Dont have exception

Comment: When I navigate to another page and navigate back, above code throw a System.Exception

Answer (score 1):

`StaticResource` and `ThemeResource` doesn't support dynamic change as you try like `DynamicResource` in WPF. BTW if you reload the view like navigating back and forward you can see the changes but this is not a good solution.

Other hand, you can achieve some dynamic change with `ThemeResource` and change eg. colors depend on the current theme (Dark, Light, High Contrast)

Futher reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources

Comment: But I see some apps on Store can do this. Color change immediately after user select color (Example: Awesome Tube from Windows 10 Store)

Comment: They most likely did it with binding, not in code like what you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a `SolidColorBrush` then modify the Color property directly.

```
var brush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["MyColor"];
brush.Color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 101, 34);
```

You can't change the resources, but you can modify their properties if you have access.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way:

App.xaml

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Dark">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <Color x:Key="UserAccentColor">#FFFFA500</Color>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UserAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource UserAccentColor}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <Color x:Key="UserAccentColor">#FFFFA500</Color>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UserAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource UserAccentColor}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
```

Change color:

```
foreach (var dict in App.Current.Resources.ThemeDictionaries)
{
    var theme = dict.Value as Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary;
    ((SolidColorBrush)theme["UserAccentBrush"]).Color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(App.Current.Resources["MyColor"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 101, 34);
```