# c# XAML thickness resource not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm getting some issues with the code below, the compiler doesn't display any errors and the program runs correctly but while the color changes the thickness doesn't.
What's wrong?
I suppose something related to the c# codebehind because if I manually change the value of the thickness resource while the app is running(the new version of vs2017 allows me to do that) everything works fine.

xaml

```
...
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key= "myColor" Color="Red"/>
    <Thickness x:Key="myThickness">1,1,1,1</Thickness>
<Page.Resources>
...
<Broder BorderBrush="{StaticResource myColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource myThickness}">something</Border>
...
```

c#

```
Thickness myThicknessVar= (Thickness)this.Resources["myThickness"];
myThicknessVar= new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);

SolidColorBrush myColorVar= (SolidColorBrush)this.Resources["myColor"];
myColorVar.Color = Colors.Green;
```

Comment: Try this for your XAML `<Thickness x:Key="myThickness" Bottom="1" Left="1" Right="1" Top="1" />`. Only thing that looks like it may be an issue

Comment: @MattL. Oh, I've already tried but visual studio doesn't let me write Bottom Left and so on, it just underlines the words and marks them as errors

Comment: This is quite strange because I can access these properties through c# (however nothing happens)

Comment: What are the errors? That may be the cause of your issues

Comment: @MattL. I restarted visual studio because I thought it to be a bug of the IDE and so it was(before doing this it underlined the text just like when you tipe random stuff), so replaced 1,1,1,1 with Bottom="1" ... but the code still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, thought this was using WPF. As for UWP it doesn't look like you can change a resource. I found this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596564/how-to-change-color-define-in-xaml-resources-in-code-uwp I've never worked with uwp so I won't be any help, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this works:

```
SolidColorBrush myColorVar = (SolidColorBrush)this.Resources["myColor"];
myColorVar.Color = Colors.Green;
```

Is that you are modifying an existing object that you have retrieved from the resource dictionary - myColorVar. Variable myColorVar is a reference to this.Resources["myColor"].

When you are doing this:

```
Thickness myThicknessVar = (Thickness)this.Resources["myThickness"];
myThicknessVar = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

You are assigning a new value to variable "myThicknessVar", without changing the actual value that is in the resource dictionary.

To attain the desired behavior you need to do two things:

1. Change the object stored in the resource dictionary:

```
this.Resources["myThickness"] = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

2. Use DynamicResource in XAML instead of StaticResource:

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource myColor}" BorderThickness="{DynamicResource myThickness}">
    <!-- something -->
</Border>
```

Comment: The first metod doesn't work, I had already tried that making your same reasoning, as for the second metod, I'm using UWP, I don't think "DynamicResource" is available for this platform

Comment: DynamicResource is available in UWP.  Did you try replacing "StaticResource" with "DynamicResource" in XAML?  You need to do both, 1 and 2, to make it work.

Comment: Look at this video (minute 12:50): https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-layout-14328?l=cSQEhy4sB_4604819052 the DynamicResource doesn't exist anymore